# Installation and usage of TagLib in c++ project

Tags: c++, unix, installation, taglib

In addition to my previous [Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45513483/taglib-tstring-h-include-not-found).

I have tried numerous [sources](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/multimedia/taglib.html) in order to find the right way how to install taglib library for c++ and use it in my project.

I am including path

```
#include <taglib/tag.h>
```

i tried including just

```
  #include <taglib>
```

but it did not work even tho `/usr/include/taglib` exists.

I am compiling my project using

```
g++ -Wall -pedantic -std=c++11 -ltaglib main.cpp -I taglib-1.11.1/toolkit
```

yet the demo from site

```
    TagLib::FileRef f("Latex Solar Beef.mp3");
TagLib::String artist = f.tag()->artist(); // artist == "Frank Zappa"
```

throws

> error: ‘FileRef’ is not a member of ‘TagLib’   TagLib::FileRef
>   f("Latex Solar Beef.mp3");   ^ main.cpp:5:18: error: expected ‘;’
>   before ‘f’   TagLib::FileRef f("Latex Solar Beef.mp3");
>                     ^ main.cpp:6:25: error: ‘f’ was not declared in this scope  TagLib::String artist = f.tag()->artist(); // artist == "Frank
>   Zappa"

When i add `#include <taglib/fileref.h>`

it throws

> main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x48): undefined reference to
>   `TagLib::FileRef::FileRef(char const*, bool,
>   TagLib::AudioProperties::ReadStyle)' main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x50):
>   undefined reference to`TagLib::FileRef::tag() const'
>   main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x68): undefined reference to
>   `TagLib::String::~String()' main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x70): undefined
>   reference to`TagLib::FileRef::~FileRef()'
>   main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x83): undefined reference to
>   `TagLib::FileRef::~FileRef()' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit
>   status

What is the right way to install and use [TagLib](http://taglib.org/api/)?

Comment: this is whole error output

Comment: I have no idea what's wrong here, but does it still complain if you split the declaration like..  TagLib::FileRef f = TagLib::FileRef("Latex Solar Beef.mp3");

Comment: @hoodaticus yes it still complains

Answer (score 0):

Try compiling in release mode by adding this option:

```
-O3
```

Comment: g++ -Wall -pedantic -std=c++11 -03 -ltaglib main.cpp -I taglib-1.11.1/toolkit ? does work either ... "unrecognized command -03"

Comment: @trolkura "capital O" , not zero

Comment: Maybe try porting it to Visual Studio and see what happens. Maybe the compiler is acting up.

Answer (score 0):

try to write in your cmakelist.txt

```
target_link_libraries(your_executable tag)
```